# Downloaded Documents from DocuSign are blank

Tags: sharepoint-2013, docusignapi, webrequest

I am downloading an envelope from DocuSign through an API [Get Envelope Documents and Certificate](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Documents%20and%20Certificate.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____67) .

Then I am doing a web request using the PUT method to save the pdf to Document Library in SharePoint.  The problem is that when I open the pdf, the document is blank.  The amount of pages is correct and the orientation, but the actual document is blank.

Comment: Does the first page indicate that the envelope documents were purged?

Comment: No, it is just a blank page.